# Is it possible to resign immediately after getting a raise in UAE?

Tags: employees, law, manual-labor, uae

I keep resigning from my company because of salary delays and financial problems of the company.

I was in my notice period. The management said that the company condition will improve and in 2 months we will give you a salary raise if you withdraw of your resignation. I accepted the offer and I went for my annual leave to my home country. While I was in my country, I found the company's condition is getting even worse and my boss was not responding to my text messages.

I came back from my annual leave and resigned again. Now they are saying I have to complete another 3 months of notice period and even the raise which was accepted before my annual leave will be discarded and in this notice period I'll get the previous salary only.

If they take back my raise, can I consider my notice period completed? Or if they want me to work my notice period, they should give me my salary raise again?

Comment: What does your contract say regarding raises and notice period?

Comment: There is no specific line for raise . Notice period is of 3 month as per contract

Comment: Did you have to sign anything to confirm that you accept the raise, or receive anything detailing the conditions of the raise? If yes, the answer to this question likely lies in that document. If not, this is probably just a question of whether a company can reduce your salary at will (and the resignation is not relevant).

Comment: @NIKHILPUROHIT Dukeling's clarification is indeed relevant here. Was that "raise but don't quit" just spoken? Was there another contract?

Comment: The only thing that really matters at the workplace is the legal contract between you and your employer. Don't put anything else (e.g. emotional or ethical consideration) above it. You are a resource for your company, nothing more (but nothing less). And what are your legal obligations is indeed country specific.

Comment: Contact a union and/or a lawyer or anyone else you trust and understanding your case. And consider also the following: you have worked in a foreign country. You could decide to never work again in that country; it is extremely likely that your former employer won't sue you in your homeland, since this is usually too expensive for corporations.

Comment: @dukeling . Yes I have got a signed document from accountant stating Feb salary as per raise and signed by accountant. There is no other contract signed for further details saying I have to stay for the period of time after raise . Just one mail was there from my senior to accept this raise on the #withdrawal of resignation # before feb.

Comment: @dukeling . Yes I have got a signed document from accountant stating Feb salary as per raise and signed by accountant. There is no other contract signed for further details saying I have to stay for the period of time after raise . Just one mail was there from my senior to accept this raise on the #withdrawal of resignation # before feb.

Answer (score 2):

> What the experts think if they are taking my raise back so my notice period is completed or if they want me to continue my salary raise should be considered??

I think that this company gave you the raise only if you did not resign.

A short time later, you resigned, so by doing that you waived that raise, as you failed to meet the condition.

I am not a lawyer, though, so it could be wise to consider contacting one to be completely sure on the short time you had that raise, and the legal aspects on the conditions of such raise.

Regarding they asking you to serve 3 months notice period, you say that such is indeed stated in your contract, so 3 months seems what you should give.

Have in mind that you actually *withdrew your resignation*, and then resigned again. As this is a new case of resignation, you have to give full notice period as stated in your contract.

Comment: "Eventually, you resigned, so by doing that you waived that raise" - what if someone resigns years later? Could they still revert the salary back to what it was? If not, why can they do it here?

Comment: @Dukeling I think that would be speculating a bit, and does not relate nor help in this scenario, where OP didn't resigned years later (they did it after returning from their leave). Although, if that happened, it could be wise to contact a lawyer to be sure on the legal aspects of it

Comment: Well, if you wouldn't say they can revert the salary if the resignation took place years later, then what's the condition on which you're basing the claim that they can do this here? The only difference between the two is time. There might be a cutoff for how long you should stay in terms of social etiquette, but I don't think that's what the question is asking. For there to be a *legal* cutoff, this would need to be (a) specified in the law, (b) specified in a document OP agreed to or (c) argued in a court of law.

Comment: @Dukeling in *this* situation it is clear that OP agreed on the raise and a short time after (days, couple weeks top, as it was a leave) resigned again. OP got that raise on a condition of withdrawing their resignation, and happened to do just the opposite (again, days later)... it would be *very* different if this happened years later and they withdrew the raise... Anyways, as suggested in the answer, it would be wise/helpful to contact a lawyer to sort those details regarding the raise and the cutoff you mention.

Answer (score 1):

The company gave you a raise on the condition that you withdraw your resignation and you accepted this offer.  You then went ahead and resigned from the company.  You cannot expect them to give you the raise that was conditional based on you not resigning.

The raise and salary have nothing to do with your notice period.  If your contract states that 3 months is the notice period you must work for 3 months after you submit your resignation.

Comment: ,the thing which matters here that the , the raise was given to withdraw my previous resignation and I have a raise document signed by the accountant from the month of February.  After knowing the company is even in worse condition I told them to continue my previous resignation and complete my notice period . In this case they are saying, that is not possible and even raise will not be considered and you have to give again 3 month of notice period . Now 1. If they are neglecting raise then the condition of withdrawal of my resignation is not applicable 2.Or the raise ?

Comment: And the raise was given on the withdrawal of my previous resignation , there was not Any agreement that I can't put it back. Or anyone knows UAE law where it is unethical ?